# Node js , mongo DB get data from multiple collections using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, foreach, async-await

> Hello im trying to get all my blogs from DB and change the author
> name from another collection from the database then rendering them to
> ejs file however the page renders before the array is filled up

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      let blogList = new Array(); 
      await Blog.find({}, function (err, foundBlog) { 
        console.log(foundBlog);
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          foundBlog.forEach(async (blog) => {
            await Author.findById(blog.author, async (err, author) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                blog.author = author.name;
                console.log('this is the blogs' + blog);
                blogList.push(blog);
                console.log('array length 1 is ' + blogList.length);
              }
            });
          });
          console.log('array length 2 is ' + blogList.length);
          console.log(blogList);
          res.render('home', { blogs: blogList });
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Try replacing your code with [this code](https://jsbin.com/bayocoriga/1/edit?js)

Answer (score 1):

Please use ref of Author in Blog. In other words make a relation of blog with author. And then your backend should be as follows:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      
         const blogs=await Blog.find({}).populate('author').exec(); // field name author is being populated.
      
          res.render('home', { blogs });
        }
    
    );

const BlogSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
 ... rest of fields,
 author:{
  type:ObjectId,
  ref:"Author" // here it is model name 
 }
});
```

With this code now your whole author object will be embedded in each blog like:

```
blog={
  name:"",
  author:{
    name:"Abc",
  }
}
```

And you can easily get author details by accessing blog.author.name.

Comment: Note to OP: this is the better approach as compared to what you are doing. Author document should be nested inside the blog document. This way, you don't need to query the `Author` collection. In fact, you can just get rid of the `Author` collection.

Comment: so ill nest the author object inside the blog collection... thank you sir for the help !

Answer (score 0):

for your query, you can explore populate in your Mongo Schema in the collection.

```
const BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 author:{
  type:ObjectId,
  ref:"Author" //here it is model name 
 }
})
const Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", BlogSchema )

const AutherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 _id:{
  type:ObjectId
 }
})
const Auther = mongoose.model("Auther", AutherSchema)

 app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
      
 const blogs = await Blog.find({}).populate('author').exec(); // field name author is being populated.
         res.send(blogs)
        }
    )
```